thumbnail asset library is not showing blender 4.3
I created an asset library using Grease Pencil, and I recently installed Blender 4.3. However, the asset I created in Blender 4.3 is not appearing in the asset library. How is this possible, and how can I fix it?


There is a lot of information that is missing here. Is your entire asset not appending when you pull it out of the asset browser or is it just your thumbnail that is missing? If it is just your thumbnail did you try troubleshooting with this method?

Only the greasepencil assets are not showing when I make them in blender 4.3, if I make it in blender 4.2 it shows it correctly. Thumbnails for assets from models made in blender 4.3 are shown correctly. (I guess i am going to use blender 4.2 for greasepencil).
